# No exception thrown when attempting to delete folder on UNC path with restricted permissions

Tags: c#, windows, permissions

In C# I performed two tests:

1. I created a directory without any access permissions on a local drive. Attempting to delete the directory programmatically throws an IOException. I would have expected an UnauthorizedAccessException, but nonetheless I did get an IOException with a message indicating "Access denied".
2. Repeating the same test, but this time on a network UNC path, I created a directory on an available UNC share, without any access permissions. When I programmatically delete the folder, it deletes without any errors or exceptions. This is the same test, same user and given the user (myself) was the creator of the directory and also the one that removed all permissions.

The same occurs when manually testing this in Windows Explorer. Why would a folder deletion be permitted on a UNC network share, when on a local drive it is not permitted? The network is a workgroup (not domain).

Attempting to add a subdirectory on the restricted folder on the network share will throw an exception and will not succeed. I don't understand why deletion is permitted when all permissions have been removed.

Comment: This might be something that you want to ask on SuperUser as well, as it is more of a Windows Security question than a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a directory the newly created directory inherits (in most cases) its access permissions from the parent folder.

So when say "without any access permissions" you are incorrect.  You are simply getting the access permission from the parent directory.

Comment: Normally this would be correct. However, in the above test cases, I  explicitly removed all inherited permissions. Thus, the folders created have literally no permissions whatsoever.